# cannot suppress all library loading messages in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have scoured stackoverflow for this exact issue, but none of the solutions seem to resolve it for me: I cannot get all library load messages to be suppressed in a chunk.

The code is simply:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_cowplot())
library(viridis)
library(vegan)
library(dplyr)
```

The markdown output is:

```
##
## Attaching package: ’gridExtra’
## The following object is masked from ’package:dplyr’:
##
## combine
##
## Attaching package: ’MASS’
## The following object is masked from ’package:dplyr’:
##
## select
```

I have also tried to include `message=FALSE` and `warning=FALSE`, `invisible()`, and the `library()` option `quietly=TRUE`, to no avail. Am I missing something completely obvious? Any help appreciated.

EDIT: I have also tried adding warn.conflicts = FALSE and quietly to library() and also suppressPackageStartupMessage() around the library loading.

If helpful, I noticed these messages are not present in my console when I run the code chunk--they seem to only appear in the pdf markdown.

Comment: Try adding `results='hide',warning=FALSE,echo=FALSE,message=FALSE` to your chunk!

Comment: All the code chunk text output options are [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#text-results). Maybe it can help

Comment: Thanks, tried adding these but still no luck; the above messages are still being shown.

Comment: if all the above did not work, You will have to brute forse. Ie use `suppressPackageStartupMessages` function to to all the above eg `suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(reshape2))`

Answer (score 0):

You want the option `include = FALSE`:

````
```{r include = FALSE}
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
theme_set(theme_cowplot())
library(viridis)
library(vegan)
library(dplyr)
```
````

Comment: I already have include = FALSE (sorry that wasn't shown earlier) and the messages still show.

Comment: this is really strange. Does the message also show up if you knit to html format?

Comment: Thanks Jrm_FRL, you are correct, it would have been very strange, but I found it was my own user error (see post I added above). Thanks for your help. I'm not sure how to close out my question?

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the runaround! I finally found out the user error--somewhere later down in my markdown file I was sourcing another R script, which was loading libraries and NOT being quiet about it. Apologies and thanks for all the input.